# Array size in PHP shown as one despite of having more elements

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xml-parsing

Following is my code which I am using for testing purposes so far. I have to use it further in my project.
It access a certain web service and retrieves data as xml. XML is brought to `$arr` array.
Address of `$url` and 3rd parameter in `client->call()` are not mentioned on purpose.

```
$url = "";
$client= new nusoap_client($url);
$param = array("status"=>"p2");
$arr = $client->call('getAllVisitByStatus',$param,'');
echo $arr."\n";
$size = sizeof($arr);
echo $size;
for($num=0; $num<986; ++$num)
{
    echo $arr[$num], "\n";
    if($arr[$num] == '>')
    {
        echo "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
}
```

If I save the data returned by `client->call()` into an array and print it with a loop then it prints the XML like this

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF - 8" standalone = "yes" ?> 
<lists> 
   <visitW> 
   <followup>  2015 - 01 - 30 00:50:00.0 </followup> 
   <person_id> 12 </person_id> 
   <remarks> nothing </remarks> 
   <treatment> doing </treatment> 
   <visit_date> 2015 - 01 - 04 - 00 - 24 - </visit_date> 
   <visit_id> 4 </visit_id> 
   <visit_type> Hesschart</visit_type> 
   </visitW>
</lists>
```

However, if take `$arr` as a string, it prints this:

```
2015-01-30 00:50:00.0 12 nothing doing 2015-01-04-00-24- 4 Hesschart
```

So, in a string it prints without tags and like this.

The problem is that when the size of array is printed, it prints 1. However, the array contains the whole XML brought as a result of service call.

When I use a loop of exact number of elements i.e. 986, then it prints the whole XML as it is.

The question is that why does it show 1 as the size of the array? Also, can this array containing XML be put in DOM Parser?

Comment: What does `->call` return? Aren't you counting the size of the parent (root) element, instead of the children?

Comment: Give us your `$arr`'s example data.

Comment: Please view the changes that I made in my question.

Comment: What does a `print_r($arr);` output when `$arr` has been assigned?

Comment: It prints the same output as that of a string.

2015-01-30 00:50:00.0 12 nothing doing 2015-01-04-00-24- 4 Hesschart